# How to scan a physical document and store it as PDF

Tags: windows-10, scanning, laser-printer

I want to scan an old receipt/letter etc. from my desk in paper form and save it to PDF. How do I do that?  NOTE: I'm using HP Color LaserJet cp3525 printer

Comment: A printer (even HP LaserJets) do not print to anything. They are printed to. I really don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: There is a [built-in PDF printer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQKTZ.jpg) already available in a standard Windows 10 configuration, regardless of what other printers you have installed.  Simply point your document to the PDF printer, instead.

Comment: @simonatrcl Sorry for the confusion. My question was not clear. I have added an **UPDATE** section to clarify my question.

Comment: It seems to my that you do not want to print but **scan** the document (paper) to PDF, am I right?

Comment: @Run5k I've added an **UPDATE** section to clarify my question.

Comment: @MichaelS. Thank you for correcting me. I've made some corrections to my original question by replacing `print` to **scan**

Comment: @nam you mean scan to print, scan a document and print at same time?

Comment: @Moab Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: I do not think this device can scan or copy, it is just a printer. Here is the manual, I searched for scan. No results... http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c01482154

Comment: @nam ok here are your user manuals for that printer, they should help you answer the question easier than we can.............https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-color-laserjet-cp3520-printer-series/3690646/model/3690647/manuals

Comment: You will need an All-in-One Printer to be able to scan. I have [this one](https://epson.com/For-Work/Printers/Inkjet/Epson-WorkForce-WF-3620-All-in-One-Printer/p/C11CD19201) at home, cheap but good. The replacement product is [WorkForce Pro WF-3720 All-in-One Printer](https://epson.com/For-Work/Printers/Inkjet/WorkForce-Pro-WF-3720-All-in-One-Printer/p/C11CF24201) for 90 USD.

Comment: If you only have a few documents, iPhones can capture documents using the camera and the Notes app and save them as PDFs, and there are apps for Android that do this as well (Microsoft Office Lens is one I've used). This would be simpler and cheaper than buying a new device.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do what you want with that printer since it is only a printer and has no built in scanner, you would need a separate scanner or an all in one laser printer that also scans documents.

[Here are your user manuals](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-color-laserjet-cp3520-printer-series/3690646/model/3690647/manuals), user guide show it only Prints, no scan function.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to purchase, borrow, or ask to use a device with scanning functionality.  In the USA, public libraries usually have a public device you can use.  However, if it is a sensitive document (medical, financial), then you might be worried about privacy, so buying a cheap scanner might be the better choice.

Smartphone cameras can be used for the scanning purpose.  Google Drive is able to make scans and save them to the drive directly.  Otherwise, you can take a regular JPG picture, then save it as PDF or embed it inside a PDF.